# when run nodemon in angular ts getting this error?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules

The problem is when I execute the npm run dev command I get the following error

node_modules is not recognized as an internal or external command

[image]

This is how the packages.json script looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"compile":"./node_modules/.bin/tsc && node server.js"
```

Might be a path issue, your command line thinks that "node_modules" is a command.